# Conditionally dependant on variables in YAML file

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I am trying to run a command using my playbook conditionally. The command is dependant on a given customer having their type value set to 'PBSTP'. If the type is set to anything else the play should not be run. I am currently trying to use this configuration but it is telling me that the conditional fails because the dict object does not contain a value for 'type'.
Is there any way to do this?

```
- command: cp -r /home/pb/scripts /home/{{ item }}/scripts
  with_items: "{{ customers }}"
  when: customers['type'] == "PBSTP"
```

In the given example I wish that the 'SESH' client does not get a directory copy of the scripts where as the 'TEST-BANK' client does.
Thank you!

```
TEST-BANK:
    type: PBSTP
    accept: 32506
    connect: 33506
    ipaddr:
      - 192.167.203.92
    subtype: INBOUND
SESH:
    type: SPOT
    accept: 32508
    connect: 33508
    ipaddr:
      - 192.167.203.63
    subtype: TIERED
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to apply `when` condition to `customers` dict (it has keys `TEST-BANK`, `SESH`, etc.).

You want to apply condition to current item in the loop iteration:

```
- command: cp -r /home/pb/scripts /home/{{ item.key }}/scripts
  with_dict: "{{ customers }}"
  when: item.value['type'] == "PBSTP"
```

Also note that you should use `with_dict`, as `with_items` will give you only keys and not it's values.

Comment: Thank you Konstantin. You are very helpful for all my ansible quieries!